# jsdom 500 error on createWindow

Tags: node.js, jsdom

Trouble with a fundamental operation.  jsdom.jsdom is returning 500 errors on createWindow.

Sample code:

```
var getaPage=function (req, res, callback) {
    jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures={
        FetchExternalResources      : ['script'],
        ProcessExternalResources    : ['script'],
        MutationEvents              : '2.0',
        QuerySelector               : false
    };

    //This is someone's sample, my real code is more complex, but this shows the error
    var htmlDoc = '<html lang="en-US">' +
        '<head>' +
        '<title>Test document</title>' +
        '<script>' +
            'var testVar = true;' +
        '</script>' +
        '<script src=\'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js\'></script>' +
        '<script>' +
        '</script>' +
        '</head>' +
        '<body id="mainPage">' +
        '</body>' +
        '</html>';

    var tstDocument=jsdom.jsdom(htmlDoc);

    var tstWindow=tstDocument.createWindow();
    //yeah, I am just trhowing this out for the moment

    var contents=[{label:'a label', value:'a value'}];
    //real values after I get this thing working
    callback(contents);
};
```

I get a 500 error (in the nodeJS console*).if I include the createWindow line.  If I comment it out, the code runs to completion and returns "contents" to the calling app. (The ajax call into this function just gets a ".fail" state with an "Internal Server Error")

*GET /sample/getaPage 500 112ms - 1.49kb

Additional information  When I examing the tstDocument object, I don't see a "createWindow" method.  Why would jsdom create an object without a "createWindow" method?

What have I missed?

Comment: You get a 500 error but how does it show up? It's an exception? A trace somewhere? (Update your question with this information.)

Comment: the 500 is on the nodeJS console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found my solution.  createWindow no longer exists in jsDom.  equivalent function is provided in the defaultView attribute.  It would have been nice if the deprecation had been cleaner than just dropping the method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492552/jsdom-jsdom-missing-a-createwindow-method