# jsdom.jsdom missing a "createWindow" method

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I am trying to use jsdom to analyze some html content.  Examples that i have seen use the .createWindow() method of a jsdom.jsdom document based on html content.

But when I try to follow these examples, my document does not have a .createWindow() method.

```
var getaPage=function (req, res, callback) {
    jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures={
        FetchExternalResources      : ['script'],
        ProcessExternalResources    : ['script'],
        MutationEvents              : '2.0',
        QuerySelector               : false
    };

    var htmlDoc = '<html lang="en-US">' +
        '</html>';

    var tstDocument=jsdom.jsdom(htmlDoc);
    for (var attr in tstDocument){
        if (attr == 'createWindow') {
            console.log('Found it');
        }else{
            console.log('not it');
        };
    };

};
```

When I run this, I get a bunch of 'not it' and no 'Found it'.

Why do I not have a .createWindow() method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jsdom's API changed quite a bit with the 1.0 release. The `createWindow()` method is from the old API. You should be able to get the document's window just by accessing `tstDocument.defaultView`, just like you'd do if you were in a browser.